# How to get an AWS EC2 instance ID from within that EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

How can I find out the `instance id` of an ec2 instance from within the ec2 instance?

Answer (score 640, accepted):

See [the EC2 documentation on the subject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html).

Run:

```
wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

If you need programmatic access to the instance ID from within a script,

```
die() { status=$1; shift; echo "FATAL: $*"; exit $status; }
EC2_INSTANCE_ID="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id || die \"wget instance-id has failed: $?\"`"
```

Here is an example of a more advanced use (retrieve instance ID as well as availability zone and region, etc.):

```
EC2_INSTANCE_ID="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id || die \"wget instance-id has failed: $?\"`"
test -n "$EC2_INSTANCE_ID" || die 'cannot obtain instance-id'
EC2_AVAIL_ZONE="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone || die \"wget availability-zone has failed: $?\"`"
test -n "$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE" || die 'cannot obtain availability-zone'
EC2_REGION="`echo \"$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE\" | sed -e 's:\([0-9][0-9]*\)[a-z]*\$:\\1:'`"
```

You may also use `curl` instead of `wget`, depending on what is installed on your platform.

Comment: @Leopd, you obviously know better than the people at Amazon who implemented EC2 and wrote the docs. Incidentally, nobody stops you from creating an alias for `169.254.169.254` in `/etc/hosts` if that makes you feel more secure, should you... care.

Comment: @leopd What if they change their DNS server and you can't get DNS any more?  Isn't that just as likely as changing their IP address for looking up resources?

Comment: What about in the Java SDK? Is there any way to get this without having to do a GET on that url? Seems strange if it's not in the SDK

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. For others trying to figure out the regular expression in the last line, here's what I came up with:  At the end of the line (`$`), find one or more digits following by one or more lowercase letters. Substitute with the digits only.  (Backslash + parentheses tell sed to remember a substring, which is recalled with `\1`.) I found this a little easier to read--the only backslashes are those required by sed:  `EC2_REGION="$(echo "$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE" | sed -e 's:\([0-9][0-9]*\)[a-z]*$:\1:')"`.

Comment: You can eliminate the magic numbers by using `http://instance-data/` instead of `169.254.169.254`

Comment: I checked this on 2016-02-04. I found that the "instance-data" hostname is (a) not listed in that documentation, and (b) does not work (for me) on a new EC2 host. The documentation -- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html -- only mentions the 169.254 address, and makes no mention of the "instance-data" hostname. i.e. use http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id

Comment: @kevinm I posted the Java SDK answer below

Comment: The `die` works in perl I think, but not in bash that I'm using on EC2. Is this a command I should get somewhere, seems useful.

Comment: `instance-data` will only be available if you're using the Amazon DNS resolvers - if you're not, it won't be available. It resolves to 169.254.169.254.

Comment: @sehe oh yes, it's a bash function; that wasn't obvious to me when reading the last  snippet.

Answer (score 208):

On Amazon Linux AMIs you can do:

```
$ ec2-metadata -i
instance-id: i-1234567890abcdef0
```

Or, on Ubuntu and some other linux flavours, `ec2metadata --instance-id` (This command may not be installed by default on ubuntu, but you can add it with `sudo apt-get install cloud-utils`)

As its name suggests, you can use the command to get other useful metadata too.

Comment: @Marc Nope. No `-` after `ec2`. It is `ec2metadata --instance-id`

Comment: The command is different on different Linuxes: on Amazon Linux it's `ec2-metadata`, on Ubuntu it seems to be `ec2metadata`.

Comment: Right James, I found the same ec2metadata to be working on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Cerin nope, this command is still the correct one on Amazon Linux 2. ```[ec2-user@ip-10-1-1-1 ~]$ ec2-metadata -i \
instance-id: <redacted> \
[ec2-user@ip-10-1-1-1 ~]$ ec2metadata \
-bash: ec2metadata: command not found```

Comment: @James Nope, not on any EC2 instance I'm using. It even suggested the correct command, ec2metadata. You're likely using a very old image.

Comment: @Cerin perhaps you are using a different Linux distribution? This command is on Amazon Linux.

Comment: Things have changed since @James' comment (8 years ago); the `ec2-metadata` command is a shell script, not a Java program.  Since the hypervisor's IMDS capabilities have been built out considerably, the only tool needed under the hood is `wget` or `curl` or similar.

Comment: On Ubuntu, **cloud-guest-utils** installs `ec2metadata` (a Python 3.x script), and **amazon-ec2-utils** installs `ec2-metadata` (a plain shell script).  The latter is written by AWS, and is also what's installed by default on Amazon Linux 2 AMIs, etc.

Answer (score 81):

On Ubuntu you can:

```
sudo apt-get install cloud-utils
```

And then you can:

```
EC2_INSTANCE_ID=$(ec2metadata --instance-id)
```

You can get most of the metadata associated with the instance this way:

```
ec2metadata --help
Syntax: /usr/bin/ec2metadata [options]

Query and display EC2 metadata.

If no options are provided, all options will be displayed

Options:
    -h --help               show this help

    --kernel-id             display the kernel id
    --ramdisk-id            display the ramdisk id
    --reservation-id        display the reservation id

    --ami-id                display the ami id
    --ami-launch-index      display the ami launch index
    --ami-manifest-path     display the ami manifest path
    --ancestor-ami-ids      display the ami ancestor id
    --product-codes         display the ami associated product codes
    --availability-zone     display the ami placement zone

    --instance-id           display the instance id
    --instance-type         display the instance type

    --local-hostname        display the local hostname
    --public-hostname       display the public hostname

    --local-ipv4            display the local ipv4 ip address
    --public-ipv4           display the public ipv4 ip address

    --block-device-mapping  display the block device id
    --security-groups       display the security groups

    --mac                   display the instance mac address
    --profile               display the instance profile
    --instance-action       display the instance-action

    --public-keys           display the openssh public keys
    --user-data             display the user data (not actually metadata)
```

Comment: Under Ubuntu lucid `apt-get install` retrieves version 0.11-0ubuntu1 which doesn't contain this utility.  It was added to the package [just afterwards](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cloud-utils-dev/cloud-utils/trunk/changes/50?start_revid=190).

Comment: The cloud-utils package is included by default on the Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS Cluster Compute AMI.

Comment: cloud-utils seems to be in RHEL/CentOS too

Answer (score 68):

Use the `/dynamic/instance-identity/document` URL if you also need to query more than just your instance ID.

`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document`

This will get you **JSON** data such as this - with only a **single request**.

```
{
    "devpayProductCodes" : null,
    "privateIp" : "10.1.2.3",
    "region" : "us-east-1",
    "kernelId" : "aki-12345678",
    "ramdiskId" : null,
    "availabilityZone" : "us-east-1a",
    "accountId" : "123456789abc",
    "version" : "2010-08-31",
    "instanceId" : "i-12345678",
    "billingProducts" : null,
    "architecture" : "x86_64",
    "imageId" : "ami-12345678",
    "pendingTime" : "2014-01-23T45:01:23Z",
    "instanceType" : "m1.small"
}
```

Comment: +1 for showing all details including instanceType in one simple call

Comment: +1 for having a fairly standard (wget only) and working line (instance-data url did not work for me on amazon linux), without installing additional packages just for this simple task.

Answer (score 51):

For all ec2 machines, the instance-id can be found in file:

```
    /var/lib/cloud/data/instance-id
```

You can also get instance id by running the following command:

```
    ec2metadata --instance-id
```

Comment: This is a very clean solution, not requiring a HTTP request.

Comment: The best possible answer actually

Comment: Great answer but I couldn't find a reference for this in the documentation. may I ask what your reference is? The concern is that if we are going to run this code in production, how do we know it won't change in the future?

Comment: All *linux* ec2 machines, perhaps, but definitely not *all* ec2 machines.  No such file on Windows.  `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log\Ec2Launch.log` contains the instance Id, but also has a whole lot of other junk.

Comment: cat the first command. This is the most simple and straightforward solution

Comment: Clean and light solution!

Comment: reference: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/23.2.2/reference/faq.html#data - it's a cloud-init thing.

Answer (score 46):

on AWS Linux:

`ec2-metadata --instance-id | cut -d " " -f 2`

Output:

`i-33400429`

Using in variables:

```
ec2InstanceId=$(ec2-metadata --instance-id | cut -d " " -f 2);
ls "log/${ec2InstanceId}/";
```

Comment: Clean and concise way. Working out of the box for an instance with Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 27):

For `.NET` People :

```
string instanceId = new StreamReader(
      HttpWebRequest.Create("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")
      .GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    .ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 26):

For powershell people:

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")
```

Comment: just different commandet: `$instanceId=(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').Content`

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest doesn't always work when running a script on said EC2 instance with a ssm send-command (or Send-SSMCommand). It doesn't really say in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1). Possibly a it is not async... which would be weird. But stefancaunter's option works with no problems so far.

Answer (score 23):

For Python:

```
import boto.utils
region=boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()['local-hostname'].split('.')[1]
```

which boils down to the one-liner:

```
python -c "import boto.utils; print boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()['local-hostname'].split('.')[1]"
```

Instead of local_hostname you could also use public_hostname, or:

```
boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()['placement']['availability-zone'][:-1]
```

Comment: All the newer versions of boto I see let you call the key "instance_id" directly. I made the relevant suggested edits.

Comment: inst_id = boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()['instance-id']

Comment: You do realise this gets the region that the instance is in, not the instance-id as the question asked for, right?

Comment: For anyone wondering, this is in boto but is not yet in boto3.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33733852 for a workaround using urllib.  There's an open feature request at https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/313  FWIW, the JS SDK also has this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/MetadataService.html  Use `new AWS.MetadataService().request('instance-id',function(error,data) { myInstanceId = data; })`

Answer (score 14):

See [this post](http://www.cloudiquity.com/2009/02/finding-information-about-an-amazon-ec2-instance/) - note that the IP address in the URL given is constant (which confused me at first), but the data returned is specific to your instance.

Comment: Link is 404ing for me

Comment: Check @DEtDev's answer below; my answer is pretty old and it looks like the link has been taken down.

Answer (score 13):

Just Type:

```
ec2metadata --instance-id
```

Comment: which AMI you are using ?

Comment: Apparently thats a command for the Amazon AMI, you should update your answer

Comment: @WédneyYuri Yes.

Comment: For an alinux2 ami I have the `ec2-metadata` command not `ec2metadata`. Unsure if this is a typo or the command has changed in the new AMI instance.

`ec2-metadata --instance-id | cut -d' ' -f2` for just the id as a string

Answer (score 11):

A more contemporary solution.

From Amazon Linux the ec2-metadata command is already installed.

From the terminal

```
ec2-metadata -help
```

Will give you the available options

```
ec2-metadata -i
```

will return

```
instance-id: yourid
```

Comment: much better than depending on the pseudo ip

Comment: combine `ec2-metadata` with your `motd`, docs here: https://coderwall.com/p/hr_9pw/motds-on-amazon-amis

Comment: In Ubuntu image the command is "ec2metadata --instance-id" and will return only the instance id value

Answer (score 10):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
aws_instance=$(wget -q -O- http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
aws_region=$(wget -q -O- http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname)
aws_region=${aws_region#*.}
aws_region=${aws_region%%.*}
aws_zone=`ec2-describe-instances $aws_instance --region $aws_region`
aws_zone=`expr match "$aws_zone" ".*\($aws_region[a-z]\)"`
```

Answer (score 10):

For Ruby:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'net/http'

metadata_endpoint = 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/'
instance_id = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( metadata_endpoint + 'instance-id' ) )

ec2 = AWS::EC2.new()
instance = ec2.instances[instance_id]
```

Comment: WTF guys?! You stole my edit! http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4035074

Comment: Sorry.  Didn't know how to say "It's a good edit.  I'm the OP.  Accept this".

Answer (score 10):

The latest Java SDK has `EC2MetadataUtils`:

In Java:

```
import com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils;
String myId = EC2MetadataUtils.getInstanceId();
```

In Scala:

```
import com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils
val myid = EC2MetadataUtils.getInstanceId
```

Answer (score 8):

A c# .net class I wrote for EC2 metadata from the http api.
I will build it up with functionality as needed. You can run with it if you like it.

```
using Amazon;
using System.Net;

namespace AT.AWS
{
    public static class HttpMetaDataAPI
    {
        public static bool TryGetPublicIP(out string publicIP)
        {
            return TryGetMetaData("public-ipv4", out publicIP);
        }
        public static bool TryGetPrivateIP(out string privateIP)
        {
            return TryGetMetaData("local-ipv4", out privateIP);
        }
        public static bool TryGetAvailabilityZone(out string availabilityZone)
        {
            return TryGetMetaData("placement/availability-zone", out availabilityZone);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the url of a given AWS service, according to the name of the required service and the AWS Region that this machine is in
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceName">The service we are seeking (such as ec2, rds etc)</param>
        /// <remarks>Each AWS service has a different endpoint url for each region</remarks>
        /// <returns>True if the operation was succesful, otherwise false</returns>
        public static bool TryGetServiceEndpointUrl(string serviceName, out string serviceEndpointStringUrl)
        {
            // start by figuring out what region this instance is in.
            RegionEndpoint endpoint;
            if (TryGetRegionEndpoint(out endpoint))
            {
                // now that we know the region, we can get details about the requested service in that region
                var details = endpoint.GetEndpointForService(serviceName);
                serviceEndpointStringUrl = (details.HTTPS ? "https://" : "http://") + details.Hostname;
                return true;
            }
            // satisfy the compiler by assigning a value to serviceEndpointStringUrl
            serviceEndpointStringUrl = null;
            return false;
        }
        public static bool TryGetRegionEndpoint(out RegionEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            // we can get figure out the region end point from the availability zone
            // that this instance is in, so we start by getting the availability zone:
            string availabilityZone;
            if (TryGetAvailabilityZone(out availabilityZone))
            {
                // name of the availability zone is <nameOfRegionEndpoint>[a|b|c etc]
                // so just take the name of the availability zone and chop off the last letter
                var nameOfRegionEndpoint = availabilityZone.Substring(0, availabilityZone.Length - 1);
                endpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(nameOfRegionEndpoint);
                return true;
            }
            // satisfy the compiler by assigning a value to endpoint
            endpoint = RegionEndpoint.USWest2;
            return false;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Downloads instance metadata
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>True if the operation was successful, false otherwise</returns>
        /// <remarks>The operation will be unsuccessful if the machine running this code is not an AWS EC2 machine.</remarks>
        static bool TryGetMetaData(string name, out string result)
        {
            result = null;
            try { result = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/" + name); return true; }
            catch { return false; }
        }

/************************************************************
 * MetaData keys.
 *   Use these keys to write more functions as you need them
 * **********************************************************
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
hostname
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
public-hostname
public-ipv4
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
*************************************************************/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply check the `var/lib/cloud/instance` symlink, it should point to `/var/lib/cloud/instances/{instance-id}` where `{instance_id}` is your instance-id.

Comment: I would not use this. You are better off using the approved HTTP request to get the metadata.

Answer (score 5):

**For C++** (using cURL):

```
    #include <curl/curl.h>

    //// cURL to string
    size_t curl_to_str(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
        ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
        return size * nmemb;
    };

    //// Read Instance-id 
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); // Initialize cURL
    CURL *curl; // cURL handler
    CURLcode res_code; // Result
    string response;
    curl = curl_easy_init(); // Initialize handler
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_to_str);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
    res_code = curl_easy_perform(curl); // Perform cURL
    if (res_code != CURLE_OK) { }; // Error
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl); // Cleanup handler
    curl_global_cleanup(); // Cleanup cURL
```

Answer (score 5):

### Simple one line

`cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_asset_tag`

or

`curl_cli -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/identify_ec2_instances.html

Comment: I like that this method doesn't assume *metadata service* access is enabled for the instance (not best practice for security), and still has *some* level of official documentation (for instances based on the *nitro* hypervisor).

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to get the all instances id list in python here is the code:

```
import boto3

ec2=boto3.client('ec2')
instance_information = ec2.describe_instances()

for reservation in instance_information['Reservations']:
   for instance in reservation['Instances']:
      print(instance['InstanceId'])
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW I wrote a FUSE filesystem to provide access to the EC2 metadata service: https://github.com/xdgc/ec2mdfs .
I run this on all custom AMIs; it allows me to use this idiom: cat /ec2/meta-data/ami-id

Answer (score 3):

In Go you can use the [goamz package](http://godoc.org/github.com/mitchellh/goamz/aws#GetMetaData).

```
import (
    "github.com/mitchellh/goamz/aws"
    "log"
)

func getId() (id string) {
    idBytes, err := aws.GetMetaData("instance-id")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error getting instance-id: %v.", err)
    }

    id = string(idBytes)

    return id
}
```

[Here's](https://github.com/mitchellh/goamz/blob/master/aws/aws.go#L180) the GetMetaData source.

Answer (score 3):

You can just make a HTTP request to GET any Metadata by passing the your metadata parameters.

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

or

```
wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

You won't be billed for HTTP requests to get Metadata and Userdata.

Else

You can use EC2 Instance Metadata Query Tool which is a  simple bash script that uses curl to query the EC2 instance Metadata from within a running EC2 instance as mentioned in documentation.

Download the tool:

```
$ wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2metadata/ec2-metadata
```

now run command to get required data.

```
$ec2metadata -i
```

Refer:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

https://aws.amazon.com/items/1825?externalID=1825

Happy To Help.. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Motivation**: User would like to Retrieve aws instance metadata.

**Solution:**
The IP address `169.254.169.254` is a link-local address (and is valid only from the instance) aws gives us link with dedicated Restful API **for Retrieving metadata of our running instance** (Note that you are not billed for HTTP requests used to retrieve instance metadata and user data) . for [Additional Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html)

**Example**:

```
//Request:
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id

//Response
ami-123abc
```

You able to get additional metadata labels of your instance using this link `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/<metadata-field>` just choose the right tags:

1. ami-id
2. ami-launch-index
3. ami-manifest-path
4. block-device
5. mapping
6. events
7. hibernation
8. hostname
9. iam
10. identity-credentials
11. instance-action
12. instance-id
13. instance-type
14. local-hostname
15. local-ipv4
16. mac
17. metrics
18. network
19. placement
20. profile
21. reservation-id
22. security-groups
23. services

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to IP port 80: Connection refuse , Port 80 is open

Comment: For an up-to-date list, curl at the parent level: `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/`

Answer (score 2):

Most simple approach is to use aws cli and `sts get-caller-identity`.

`INSTANCE_ID=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query UserId --output text | cut -d : -f 2)`

- This way you don't need to authorize against metadata endpoint manually.
- It works on any unix AMI in contrast to `ec2-metadata` command that is only available for amazon linux AMIs

Answer (score 1):

In the question you have mentioned the user as root, one thing I should mention is that the instance ID is not dependent on the user.

For **Node** developers,

```
var meta  = new AWS.MetadataService();

meta.request("/latest/meta-data/instance-id", function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the instance metadata use

```
wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

Answer (score 1):

For a Windows instance:

```
(wget http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id).Content
```

or

```
(ConvertFrom-Json (wget http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document).Content).instanceId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` 

AMI=`curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id`

echo $AMI
```

This should helps you,

Answer (score 0):

For PHP:

```
$instance = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document));
$id = $instance['instanceId'];
```

Edit per @John

Comment: But why would you use GuzzeHttp for that purpose if you have curl and native functions in PHP ?

Comment: It's my preference.  I use guzzle for many other things, it is a common prerequisite for many other packages as well.

Comment: $instance = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document'),true);
$id = $instance['instanceId'];

I know Guzzle is widespread, I've never touched it myself. For such a simple task I'd provide the lightest approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative approach for PHP:**

```
$instance = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document'),true);
$id = $instance['instanceId'];
print_r($instance);
```

That will provide a lot of data about the instance, all nicely packed in an array, no external dependencies.
As it's a request that never failed or delayed for me it should be safe to do it that way, otherwise I'd go for curl()

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

You will be able to see different types of attributes which are provided by aws.

[Use this link to view more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)

Answer (score 0):

All meta-data related to EC2 resource can be accessed by the EC2 instance itself with the help of the following command being executed:

CURL :

```
http://169.254.169.254/<api-version>/meta-data/<metadata-requested>
```

For your case: "**metadata-requested**" should be **instance-id** , "**api-version**" is usually **latest** that can be used.

Additional Note: You can also get information related to below EC2 attributes using the above command.

ami-id,
ami-launch-index,
ami-manifest-path,
block-device-mapping/,
hostname,
iam/,
instance-action,
instance-id,
instance-type,
local-hostname,
local-ipv4,
mac,
metrics/,
network/,
placement/,
profile,
public-hostname,
public-ipv4,
public-keys/,
reservation-id,
security-groups,
services/,

For more details please follow this link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Answer (score 0):

For AWS elastic beanstalk eb cli run `eb tags --list`

Answer (score 0):

For .NET code it is very simple:
`var instanceId=Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.InstanceId`

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

won't work if you are using V2 of the meta data service(IMDSv2). For V2, you need to get a an authentication token first to get authenticated, otherwise you will get an error like

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Username/Password Authentication Failed
```

To get the instance id, you can run

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"`
```

and then use this token in your request.

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also install **awscli** and use it to get all the info you wish:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=your-region aws ec2 describe-instances
```

You'll get lots of output so be sure to grep by your idetifier such as ip and print some more lines:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=your-region aws ec2 describe-instances | grep your-ip -A 10 | grep InstanceId
```

Comment: catch-22 if you don't know your region or don't want to have the creds baked into the instance