# EC2 instance scheduler

Tags: amazon-ec2

I would like to ask, what automatic tools are there to 
start Amazon EC2 instance at 08:00AM
and stop it on 16:00
(And where to run it from?)

Comment: You may find more info about how to use the Amazon EC2 Command Line
Tools for scheduling instances in [this
thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413029/auto-shutdown-and-start-amazon-ec2-instance).

Comment: FYI, for anyone looking for answers here... a lot of the services mentioned below are now dead links. We're currently using https://awssomesauce.com with much success.

Comment: For a lightweight solution, I'd suggest to [Schedule EC2 Start / Stop using AWS Lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38371889/4058484), it costs less than $0.0004 USD/month.

Comment: However, it seems more expensive if you consider developer labor costs. I use [Cloud Scheduler](https://scheduler.gncloud.io/) service, and it costs about $ 10 a month.

Answer (score 5):

The company I work for had customers regularly asking about this so we've written a freeware EC2 scheduling app available here:

http://blog.simple-help.com/2012/03/free-ec2-scheduler/

It works on Windows and Mac, lets you create multiple daily/weekly/monthly schedules and lets you use matching filters to include large numbers of instances easily or includes ones that you add in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I run my instances through a service called [Scalarium](http://www.scalarium.com/) - it has this time-based autoscaling. :)

Comment: @brainray It's now available as OpsWorks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well to shut the servers down, you could just schedule a task on the server(s) itself to tell it to shutdown at 16:00.

However if you use the Amazon EC2 Command Line Tools you can run commands from your workstation to start and stop instances:

- http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/index.html?ApiReference-cmd-RunInstances.html

In order to set up the Command Line Tools on your workstation for Mac/Linux the following guides may be useful:

- http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/01/26/starting-amazon-ec2-with-mac-os-x/
- http://cloud-computing.learningtree.com/2010/09/28/using-the-amazon-ec2-command-line-tools-and-api/

You could even configure these commands to run when you boot your workstation, or schedule them on your workstation.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon doesn't offer any functionality to support this.

The preferred solution (at present) is to [run a cron task from an existing server](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/message.jspa?messageID=184346).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is, but I believe that a lot of people have interest in such a product. I've actually got a product that does the opposite of what you need -- it stops a machine after a predetermined amount of time ;-). My guess is that you're looking to save EC2 $$$ by running your instances only during daytime hours. If that's the case then I believe my existing product could easily be twisted to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running a job on another instance that is running 24/7 or you can use a 3rd party service such as [Ylastic](http://ylastic.com/features.html) or [Rocket Peak](http://www.rocketpeak.co).

If you want to set it up yourself, for example, in C# the code to stop a server is quite straightforward:

public void stopInstance(string instance_id, string AWSRegion)
        {
            RegionEndpoint myAWSRegion = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(AWSRegion);
            AmazonEC2 ec2 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey, myAWSRegion);
            ec2.StopInstances(new StopInstancesRequest().WithInstanceId(instance_id));
        }