# Possible to run socket.io server.js file automatically?

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-web-services, chat

I make chat messaging but I need to start server daily for that there is any possibility to start the server automatically in AWS or any other ways.

```
// Setup basic express server
var io = require('../..')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, function () {
   console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to start the server daily? Why not just leave it running?

Comment: how to run server as long ?

Comment: You just leave it be. Don't turn off your pc.

Comment: No way working for client, if there is any other way.. I mention server that as socket server (server.js) in socket.io

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Shutdown and Start Amazon EC2 Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413029/auto-shutdown-and-start-amazon-ec2-instance)