# Find region from within an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to look up the region of an instance from within the instance?

I'm looking for something similar to the method of [finding the instance id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/find-out-the-instance-id-from-within-an-ec2-machine).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out the instance id from within an ec2 machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/find-out-the-instance-id-from-within-an-ec2-machine)

Comment: Short answer for anyone who don't care about all the shell scripts:  get the availability zone from `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone` and remove the last character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the instance id from within an ec2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/how-to-get-the-instance-id-from-within-an-ec2-instance)

Comment: For those reading post mid-2020, you can now use `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region`

Answer (score 190, accepted):

That URL (http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document) doesn't appear to work anymore. I get a 404 when I tried to use it. I have the following code which seems to work though:

```
EC2_AVAIL_ZONE=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`
EC2_REGION="`echo \"$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE\" | sed 's/[a-z]$//'`"
```

Comment: This is to be run *inside* the EC2 instance and is powered by AWS's backends. It will not work anywhere else (essentially because that IP is an APIPA). Also there is no way to get this information directly from inside the instance without connecting to a metadata source. This assumes that the 169.254.169.254 API is available, and your script should handle network failures accordingly. `ec2-metadata` is just a wrapper for this API, but essentially does the same thing.

Comment: In all honesty when I came up with that 2-liner I was just poking about the API looking for anything I could use to identify the correct region. The AWS metadata API is fully documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: Much simpler sed replace command than the one provided for the EC2_REGION: `sed 's/[a-z]$//`

Comment: The IID sure does work, so looking at it is cleaner than this assumption about how amazon will choose zone names.

Comment: I wonder if the people who can't get 169.254.169.254 to work have accidentally firewalled it.

Comment: Just for the record, I just successfully retrieved a JSON document that included the AZ from `http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document` in `us-west-2` (Oregon) region. Don't know if it _wasn't_ working, but it definitely _is_ working (for me!) now.

Comment: If this is in a bootscript, the metadata service may not be instantiated yet - if so, wait and try again. I've seen it take 10-15 seconds after boot for the metadata location to become available.

Comment: You can avoid calling sed `echo "${EC2_AVAIL_ZONE: : -1}"`. In bash 4.2+ you can remove space between two `:`.

Comment: Alternatively to both `sed` and bashisms, you can use this much more portable substitution: `EC2_REGION=${EC2_AVAIL_ZONE%?}`

Comment: Even simpler `sed`: `sed 's/.$/'` because the `.` in regex matches any single last character.

Comment: I prefer to remove "only if present" and "only known possibilities" (exactly like the `sed` of dannosaur) like so : `"${EC2_AVAIL_ZONE%[a-z]}"`

Comment: Made a small improvement to make it easier to use in Ansible: `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=\`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/[a-z]$//'\``

Comment: With bash we can use parameter expansion to make the second line more concise and without creating separate processes:
`EC2_REGION=${EC2_AVAIL_ZONE%[a-z]}`

Comment: `/latest/meta-data/placement/region` exists now, no idea if it did when you answered...

Comment: Okay `placement/region` metadata category was added in the 2020-08-24 version.

Answer (score 94):

There is one more way of achieving that:

```
REGION=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document|grep region|awk -F\" '{print $4}'`

echo $REGION

us-east-1
```

Comment: Should this work in any region/az (and on any AMI)? I'm getting `404 - Not Found` trying to `GET` that URL from a machine in `us-east-1a`.

Comment: @AdamMonsen perhaps it was a transient error. I'm on us-east-1a and it works great.

Comment: With jq: `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r .region`

Comment: With awk: ```curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | awk -F\" '/region/ {print $4}'```

Comment: This is not secure or safe to rely on.

Answer (score 48):

```
ec2-metadata --availability-zone | sed 's/.$//'
```

For debian based systems, the command is without dash.

```
ec2metadata --availability-zone | sed 's/.$//'
```

Comment: Get pure string with only the region name: `ec2-metadata --availability-zone | sed 's/placement: \(.*\).$/\1/'`

Comment: `ec2-metadata` doesn't seem to be something that's available by default - can you include installation instructions?

Answer (score 47):

If you are OK with using `jq`, you can run the following:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq .region -r
```

I guess it's the cleanest way.

Answer (score 45):

At some point since most of these answers have been posted, AWS did the reasonable thing and implemented a new path: `latest/meta-data/placement/region`.

This means getting the region should be as simple as

```sh
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region
```

EDIT: It's also probably worth mentioning that this endpoint was made available in the 2019-10-01 release of the metadata API. Make sure your instance supports that version or later before using this by checking `http://169.254.169.254/`.

Comment: This worked for me on some instances, but on others I get 404 Not Found, even through the latest available release is 2020-10-27.

Comment: Huh, try just `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement`. Does `region` come back as one of the listed options?

Comment: It turned out that the problematic instances were running without restart since before `region` endpoint was added, which is why it was unavailable - as [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-categories.html).

Comment: Is the date correct?  According to their docs this category was added in the 2020-08-24 version.

Comment: @Andy That's interesting... I would venture to say that AWS may have that wrong, since it's obvious it was available before 2020-08-24 seeing as the answer dates to a couple of months earlier.

Answer (score 27):

If you want to avoid regular expression, here's a one-liner you can do with Python:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | python -c "import json,sys; print json.loads(sys.stdin.read())['region']"
```

Comment: This answer should be higher!

Comment: @KostasDemiris I agree, much rather read the value in from the JSON structure than a regular expression.

Comment: I agree this seems to be the best way to do it if you don't have jq installed. You would really expect AWS to expose this as something like http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region ...

Answer (score 18):

Easiest I found so far

```
 curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/.$//'
```

Comment: This has the benefit of no non-default dependencies and it's only a single line.

Answer (score 17):

You can use ec2-metadata:

```
ec2-metadata -z | grep -Po "(us|sa|eu|ap)-(north|south|central)?(east|west)?-[0-9]+"
```

Comment: With this, if you're in `eu-central-1` you're screwed.

Comment: `central` didn't exist when I initially wrote my answer. It's added now.

Comment: A script that breaks every time AWS adds a new region doesn't seem like a particularly strong solution, to me.

Comment: Instead of grep, `awk '{split($2,arr,"-"); print arr[1]"-"arr[2]}'` will keep just the first two components of the AZ name.

Comment: @dskrvk If you just keep the first two components, how do you distringuish between `eu-west-1`, `eu-west-2` and `eu-west-3` (Also `us-west-1` and `us-west-2`) @OP: just matching `'[a-z][a-z]-[a-z]*-[0-9][0-9]*'` seems safer (that is a basic regex, it can be made shorter with an extended RE). (The current regex will break on the `ca` region, the `af` regions and the `me` region)

Answer (score 14):

very simple one liner

```
export AVAILABILITY_ZONE=`wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`
export REGION_ID=${AVAILABILITY_ZONE:0:${#AVAILABILITY_ZONE} - 1}
```

Comment: That's two lines

Comment: But this is not working on us-west-1 region. Returns `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: instance-data; Name or service not known` error.

Comment: @S.K.Venkat That is likely related to your VPC's DNS settings... Using the IP for the metadata-api seems safer (half of the other answers does that)

Answer (score 7):

Get the region from the availability zone, strip off the last letter of it.

```
ec2-metadata -z | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/[a-z]$//'
```

Answer (score 5):

If you work with json - use right tools. jq much powerful in this case.

```
# curl -s curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r '.region'
eu-west-1
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're able to use the AWS Java SDK, there is now a method that will return the current region name (such as "us-east-1", "eu-west-1"):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/regions/Regions.html#getCurrentRegion()

Answer (score 4):

This is the cleanest solution I found:

`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document |sed -n 's/  "region" : "\(.*\)"/\1/p'`

E.g.,

`export REGION=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document |sed -n 's/  "region" : "\(.*\)"/\1/p')`

- Doesn't make an API call, uses EC2 instance meta-data
- Only uses curl, and basic sed, so no dependencies on SDKs or tools not likely to be installed.
- Doesn't attempt to parse the Availability Zone name, so no worries if AWS changes AZ/Region name format

Comment: Yep perfect, thanks. This result can easily be deserialized into a json object.

Comment: I'm getting a comma at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144330/135640, with bash 4.2+ we can just strip the last char from the availability zone:

```
$ region=`curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`
$ region=${region::-1}
$ echo $region
us-east-1
```

This assumes AWS continues to use a single character for availability zones appended to the region.

Comment: We've always been able to strip the last character in shell: `region=${region%?}`

Comment: This in essence is the same answer which is in "Systems Operations on AWS" course from aws.qwiklabs.com (unfortunately behind a paywall). "Lab 1 - Auditing Your AWS Resources with AWS Systems Manager and AWS Config" has this code: `AZ=\`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone\`` `export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AZ::-1}`

Answer (score 4):

2 liner that works as long as you are using ec2.internal as your search domain:

```
az=$(curl -s http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
region=${az:0:${#az} - 1}
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone wanting to do this with good ol powershell

```
$var = (curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | Select-String-Pattern "Zone" | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "region")
echo $var
```

Answer (score 4):

## 2024 - There are two types of calls

### IMDSv2 (Recommended)

You must retrieve an auth token before getting meta data. The following call will set an environment variable for you to reuse.

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"`
```

Use the auth token to get the region (with other APIs calls too)

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN"
```

### IMDSv1

No token is required in v1. Only works if v2 is set to optional (see screenshot below). **You will see an empty string response if you try v1 in a v2-only environment.**

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region
```

### How do I know which version to use?

Use v2 if you can. If you have legacy instances and need this data now, use v1 with a roadmap to migration.

[image: v1]

### Region vs Availability Zone (us-east-1 vs us-east-1a)

- **Region** - Regional location of the instance. Returns the same region data as on AWS's region dropdown. Examples: us-east-2, ap-southeast-1.
- **Availability Zone** - Returns the specific zone within a region, denoted by the character at the end of a region. This will mirror the subnet mapped to the instance. Use the availability zone API call instead of the region API call to get this data. Examples: us-east-2a, us-east-2c, ap-southeast-1b

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-categories.html

### What is 169.254.169.254?

It's a special-use address. It only works within the EC2 instance.

Detailed answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/427018/what-is-this-ip-address-169-254-169-254

Comment: I recommend just running the IMDSv2 commands, as they also work on machines configured with IMDSv1.

Answer (score 3):

Or don't make Ubuntu or this tool a requirement and simply do:

```
: "${EBS_VOLUME_AVAILABILITY_ZONE:=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)}"
: ${EBS_VOLUME_REGION:="${EBS_VOLUME_AVAILABILITY_ZONE%%*([![:digit:]])}"}
```

Comment: Note that this only works because __currently__ the availability zone is always the region name with a lower-case letter appended to it (e.g. region is "us-west-1", zone is "us-west-1a").  If Amazon ever breaks this pattern, then the logic above will no longer work.

Answer (score 3):

This works for eu-central-1 as well as the various letter zones. (I don't have enough rep to reply to the sed answer above)

```
ec2-metadata --availability-zone | sed 's/[a-z]$//'
```

Comment: It should be `ec2metadata --availability-zone | sed 's/.$//'` (without dash)

Answer (score 3):

If you're running on windows, you can use this powershell one-liner:

```
$region=(Invoke-RestMethod "http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document").region
```

Answer (score 1):

For finding out information about the EC2 you are logged into, you can use the 
ec2-metadata tool.

You can install the tool by following [this link.](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1825?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1)
After installing the tool, you can run

`# ec2-metadata -z`

to find out the region.

This tools comes installed with the latest (10.10) Ubuntu AMIs,

Comment: This is incorrect.  `ec2-metadata -z` only shows the availability zone, not the region.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get region using JS, this should work :

```
meta.request("/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone",function(err,data){
        if(err)
                console.log(err);
        else{
                console.log(data);
                str = data.substring(0, data.length - 1);
                AWS.config.update({region:str});
                ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
            }
     });
```

This was the mapping found from AWS DOCS, in response to metadata API call, just trim the last character should work.

```
  eu-west-1a :eu-west-1
  eu-west-1b :eu-west-1
  eu-west-1c :eu-west-1
  us-east-1a :us-east-1
  us-east-1b :us-east-1
  us-east-1c :us-east-1
  us-east-1d :us-east-1
  ap-northeast-1a :ap-northeast-1
  ap-northeast-1b :ap-northeast-1
  us-west-1a :us-west-1
  us-west-1b :us-west-1
  us-west-1c :us-west-1
  ap-southeast-1a :ap-southeast-1
  ap-southeast-1b :ap-southeast-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Was also looking for a solution to find region from the instance and here is my pure Bash solution:

```
az=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
region=${az:0:${#az}-1}
```

unless there are regions where AZ has more than two letters, which I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simpler way to do it, you can look at /etc/resolv.conf and find a line like "search us-west-2.compute.internal". For example:

```
$ grep "^search" /etc/resolv.conf | sed "s:.* ::; s:\..*::"
us-west-2
```

Answer (score 1):

All this no longer works on AMI Linux 2... I found this offline (undocumented) approach:

```
REGION=`cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/ebenvinfo/region`
echo $REGION

# output example:
us-east-1
```

Comment: It seems to be the only way to get it on Amazon Linux 2023 as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IMDSv2, you'll need the token first.

Here's an example using bash, which also depends on curl:

```
function get-aws-region() {
  imdsv2_token="$(
    curl -s -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" \
            -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 1"
  )"
  curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region \
         -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $imdsv2_token"
}
```

This gets a very short-lived token and uses it to get the region.

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest IMDSv2, we need to get the token and use the token while retrieving the metadata.

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"`
EC2_AVAIL_ZONE=$(curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
EC2_REGION=$(curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ec2metadata` (no dash) is the current command to provide you all the aws hosting info about your ec2 box. this is the most elegant and secure approach. (`ec2-metadata` is the old, no longer valid command.)

Comment: This could depend on the virtual box type you've selected. I stick with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

A method using only egrep, which should work on most any linux instance spun up without having to install any extra tooling. I tested this against a list of all current AWS regions and they all match.

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | egrep -o '(\w)+-(\w)+-[0-9]'`

#### Explanation of the REGEX:

- "(\w)+"   This matches any number of letters
- "-"   matches only a single dash
- "[0-9]"   matches any 1 number

#### If you want this into a variable do:

`region=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | egrep -o '(\w)+-(\w)+-[0-9]')`

Answer (score 0):

For the sed and curl solution it looks like format has changed a bit.
For me works

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | sed -n 's/ "region" : "\(.*\)"[,]/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update 03-25-2024

For those who use Amazon Linux 2023 instance type, the command

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
```

will get 401 error. Below is my command to get AZ info

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` && curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
```