# AmazonS3Client(credentials) is deprecated

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, deprecated

I'm trying to read the files available on Amazon S3, as the question explains the problem. I couldn't find an alternative call for the deprecated constructor.

Here's the code:

```
private String AccessKeyID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private String SecretAccessKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static String bucketName     = "documentcontainer";
private static String keyName     = "test";
//private static String uploadFileName    = "/PATH TO FILE WHICH WANT TO UPLOAD/abc.txt";

AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKeyID, SecretAccessKey);

void downloadfile() throws IOException
{

    // Problem lies here - AmazonS3Client is deprecated
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        try {
        System.out.println("Downloading an object...");
        S3Object s3object = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
                bucketName, keyName));
        System.out.println("Content-Type: "  +
                s3object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
        InputStream input = s3object.getObjectContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) break;

            System.out.println("    " + line);
        }
        System.out.println();
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
          //do something
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        // do something
    }
 }
```

Any help? If more explanation is needed please mention it.
I have checked on the sample code provided in .zip file of SDK, and it's the same.

Comment: You have to use `AwsClientBuilder` class as alternative.

Comment: @franklinsijo code sample or source to read from?

Comment: Can you add it as an answer? I'll edit your answer with a small snippet of code and accept it.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/client-constructors-now-deprecated/

Comment: Is it OK to hard code the key pair in this file? Where would this file be when you deploy your web app publicly? Isn't this a security issue?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can either use [AmazonS3ClientBuilder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3ClientBuilder.html) or
[AwsClientBuilder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html) as alternatives.

For S3, simplest would be with `AmazonS3ClientBuilder`.

```
BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key", "secret_key"); 

AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
    .build();
```

Comment: Was there any reason behind this deprecation, are there any benefits of using AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard() vs new AmazonS3Client (from the previous SDKs)

Comment: Both `AmazonS3ClientBuilder` and `AwsClientBuilder` are not present in the latest NuGet packages for .Net 4.0, but various methods are depreciated including `StoredProfileAWSCredentials` (which I am currently using).
Does anyone know the recommended approach for .Net 4.0?

Comment: As you use AmazonS3ClientBuilder, myClient.setRegion() no longer works. You've got to AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredential().withRegion("eu-west-1").build();

Comment: AWSStaticCredentialsProvider is also depricated @franklinsijo

Comment: @rockstarjindal The client builder are better than old constructor in following ways. Clients created with builders are Immutable. Client must have explicit region. Builders provide a cleaner chaining API.

Answer (score 15):

Use the code listed below to create an S3 client without credentials:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
```

An usage example would be a lambda function calling S3.

Comment: thanks but only worked for me when i included withRegion()

Comment: A client created via the builders must have a region that is defined either explicitly (i.e. by calling withRegion) or as part of the DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain. If the builder can’t determine the region for a client, an SdkClientException is thrown.

Answer (score 10):

You need to pass the region information through the

```
com.amazonaws.regions.Region object.

Use AmazonS3Client(credentials, Region.getRegion(Regions.REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_REGION))
```

Comment: Where do I get the region from ? What is an example of it? And why does it need a region?

Comment: Please see this link to find the region in AWS
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249488/find-region-from-within-an-ec2-instance

Comment: What if I had this before: `AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new AnonymousAWSCredentials());` ? It has no region, no?

Comment: You can always select the default region: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/regions/Regions.html#DEFAULT_REGION

Answer (score 2):

You can create S3 default client as follows(with aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.232):

```
AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
```

Comment: Where is it getting the credentials from?

Comment: From AWS documentaion at :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html                                                             
You can do this in the following ways:
1.Use the default credential provider chain (recommended). 
2.Use a specific credential provider or provider chain.
3.Supply the credentials yourself. 
It is recommended to use IAM roles. E.g. for AWS lambda, create an IAM role which has access to S3 and create the client in lambda code. Supply this Role while configuring your lambda, similarly for EC2 instance or ECS etc.

Comment: could you explain this a little bit more? "1.Use the default credential provider chain"

Comment: The default client is the same of: (AmazonS3)standard().build(); That does not use credencial! And how to acess this? You will access if you are in the same cluster, EXAMPLE: If you have an EC2 in the same Cluster of a AWS S3. Understand? But Localhost you will not access...

Answer (score 2):

Deprecated with only creentials in constructor, you can use something like this:

```
 val awsConfiguration = AWSConfiguration(context)
 val awsCreds = CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(context, awsConfiguration)
 val s3Client = AmazonS3Client(awsCreds, Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the AWS SDK for Java 2.x, one can also build its own credentialProvider like so:

// Credential provider

```java
package com.myproxylib.aws;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProvider;

public class CustomCredentialsProvider implements AwsCredentialsProvider {

    private final String accessKeyId;
    private final String secretAccessKey;

    public CustomCredentialsProvider(String accessKeyId, String secretAccessKey) {
        this.secretAccessKey = secretAccessKey;
        this.accessKeyId = accessKeyId;
    }

    @Override
    public AwsCredentials resolveCredentials() {
        return new CustomAwsCredentialsResolver(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);
    }

}
```

// Crenditals resolver

```java
package com.myproxylib.aws;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentials;

public class CustomAwsCredentialsResolver implements AwsCredentials {

    private final String accessKeyId;
    private final String secretAccessKey;

    CustomAwsCredentialsResolver(String accessKeyId, String secretAccessKey) {
        this.secretAccessKey = secretAccessKey;
        this.accessKeyId = accessKeyId;
    }

    @Override
    public String accessKeyId() {
        return accessKeyId;
    }

    @Override
    public String secretAccessKey() {
        return secretAccessKey;
    }
}
```

// Usage of the provider

```java
package com.myproxylib.aws.s3;

public class S3Storage implements IS3StorageCapable {

    private final S3Client s3Client;

    public S3Storage(String accessKeyId, String secretAccessKey, String region) {

        this.s3Client = S3Client.builder().credentialsProvider(new CustomCredentialsProvider(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey)).region(of(region)).build();
    }
```

NOTE:

1. of course, the library user can get the credentials from wherever he wants, parse it into a java Properties before calling the S3 constructor.
2. **When possible, favour the other methods mentionned in other answers and doc.** My use case was necessary for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.16.12'

val key = "XXX"
val secret = "XXX"
val credentials = BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret)
val s3 = AmazonS3Client(
    credentials, com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(
        Regions.US_EAST_2
    )
)
val expires = Date(Date().time + 1000 * 60 * 60)

val keyFile = "13/thumbnail_800x600_13_photo.jpeg"
val generatePresignedUrlRequest = GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(
    "bucket_name",
    keyFile
)
generatePresignedUrlRequest.expiration = expires
val url: URL = s3.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest)

GlideApp.with(this)
    .load(url.toString())
    .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
    .into(image)
```