# aws sdk node default region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I plan to set Instance profile credentials to allow the elastic beanstak + docker to read dynamoDB in the same region.

I am trying to add as few environment variables as possible.

I am wondering if it is possible to let the sdk to set the region according to it's EC2's region?
or I do need a extra variable in the app and set it at deployment time?

Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to derive the Region from the [EC2 Instance Metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html).  You'll have to trim region from the Availability zone (like us-east-1a => us-east-1) and query the EC2 Instance Metadata API, but definitely doable: [Instance Metadata Categories](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-categories.html) (look for placement/availability-zone)

Related:

- [Find region from within an EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249488/find-region-from-within-an-ec2-instance)
- [How to get the instance id from within an ec2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/how-to-get-the-instance-id-from-within-an-ec2-instance)

Comment: thank you for the guidance! We also have plan to move to eks and would like approach work without code change?