# How do you deploy aws-xray-daemon in Docker swarm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm, aws-xray

I'm trying to deploy [amazon/aws-xray-daemon](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-xray-daemon) to my docker swarm.

I didn't do much in terms of configuration because there's not much I can see to configure in [the README.md](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-daemon)

```
services:
  xrayd:
    image: amazon/aws-xray-daemon
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        delay: 2m
```

I get the following in the logs

```
2021-02-27T04:50:38Z [Info] Initializing AWS X-Ray daemon 3.2.0
2021-02-27T04:50:38Z [Info] Using buffer memory limit of 78 MB
2021-02-27T04:50:38Z [Info] 1248 segment buffers allocated
2021-02-27T04:50:39Z [Error] Unable to retrieve the region from the EC2 instance EC2MetadataRequestError: failed to get EC2 instance identity document
caused by: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Get http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document: dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connect: network is unreachable
2021-02-27T04:50:39Z [Error] Cannot fetch region variable from config file, environment variables and ec2 metadata.
```

I gave the EC2 instance full `xray:*` in IAM as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the problem.  `docker stack deploy` does not update the `network.*.internal` setting.  So even when I changed it to `network.*.internal: false`  it never took the change.

I had to delete and redeploy the stack to get it working.

```
services:
  xrayd:
    image: amazon/aws-xray-daemon
    # command: --log-level warn
    command: --log-level error
    networks:
      - xray
    logging:
      driver: none
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        delay: 2m
        max_attempts: 2
networks:
  xray:
    internal: false
    attachable: false
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding would be that X-Ray daemon would not be able to get ec2 metadata - https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-daemon/blob/7494caf05b6f5c1e8c9a59ebefc64b8f822983cd/pkg/conn/conn.go#L152. My recommendation would be to set region explicitly using AWS_REGION environment variable. Also, as a debugging step I would recommend to see if you're able to get ec2 meta data manually. You can follow this post ([Find region from within an EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249488/find-region-from-within-an-ec2-instance)) to check this for your ec2 instance.