# Schedule to create AMI weekly from a running instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have few servers running on Amazon's EC2 and I would like to backup the image (create AMI) every week (replacing the old image). 
Is there any way to automate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [command line tools](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateImage.html) to create an ami. Something like `ec2-create-image -n "<image name here>" <your instancId here>`.  Put that in a cron entry that is scheduled weekly and you are done.  You should be able to use the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/find-out-the-instance-id-from-within-an-ec2-machine) to figure out what your instance id is programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [AWS Lambda to create AMIs automatically](https://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2017/aws-instance-automated-ami-creation-deletion-system/). The whole setup should be completed in around 10 minutes along with the schedule that you like.