# Get public dns name of a ec2 instance using ec2 command line tools in bash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have name of the a ec2 instance and want to do ssh to it.  How can I figure out the 'Public DNS' of the ec2 instance using the ec2 instance name.

I want to do it using bash.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have name of ec2 instance"?. In ec2, name is nothing but a tag assigned to instance.

Comment: By name I meant the instance ID

Answer (score 27):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-12abc34 --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName'
```

Where i-12abc34 is your instance id

Comment: If you don't want to get JSON result and need plain text DNS – add `--output text` to the command.

Answer (score 10):

You can query the [instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) service.

Using curl:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
```

Using wget:

```
wget -qO - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
```

If brave, [actual bash](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bashs-built-devtcp-file-tcpip):

```
exec 3<> /dev/tcp/169.254.169.254/80
echo -e "GET /latest/meta-data/public-hostname HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" >&3
cat <&3
```

(The last one leaves the connection open for me, so the `cat` gets stuck. The headers are also present in the output)

(This is from the instance itself and need access to the instnace - it is not the instance name-related version. There are enough of those answers here)

Comment: @Geoff Still works for me. Is IMDSv1 enabled on the instance? (I'll need to check if a v2 version exists)

Answer (score 7):

Using the EC2 API tools:

```
# Region is only needed if not in us-east-1
$ ec2-describe-instances --region <region> <instance id>
```

Using the unified [AWS CLI tool](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
$ aws --region <region> ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids <instance id≥
```

I prefer the unified tool as it offers comprehensive and consistent data.

Comment: You can further restric the ouput to Public DNS name only using the ```--query``` parameter, like this ```--query "Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName"```

Answer (score 4):

If you install the cloud-utils tool as described in this answer it's much more straight
forward.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600619/28672

```
ec2-metadata --public-ipv4
> public-ipv4: 54.200.4.52
```

Comment: and equivalently: ec2-metadata --public-hostname, for the hostname

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "figure out". If you mean figuring out yourself, you cannot. The public DNS name has nothing to do with the ec2 instance name. The public DNS name is composed of public IP address, region/availability zone, type of service, aws domain name, etc. For example, ec2-xx-xxx-x-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com. Because the public IP address is changed every time you stop and start your instance, unless you use an elastic IP address, your public DNS name will be changed.

If you mean figure out by using AWS API or CLI tool, you can. Using EC2 CLI, you should use command 
**ec2-describe-instances instance_id**. Again, the instance has to be running and the public DNS does change after stop/start.