# AWS get ELB Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I created one ELB and attached a few instances to this ELB. So when I login into one of these instance, I would like to type a command or run a nodejs script that can return me the its ELB name, is it possible? I know I can look up on AWS console but I'm looking for a way to look it up programmatically. If possible, I would like to see how it is done in AWS Nodejs SDK

Comment: I read this doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html but did not see they mention anything about ELB

Answer (score 0):

You do not run nodejs on an elb instance. elb is proxy to load balance client requests to your app server where you run nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the aws command line tools (http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers
```

Parse the JSON output for the instance ID (which you can get using this answer: [Find out the instance id from within an ec2 machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/find-out-the-instance-id-from-within-an-ec2-machine)) and look for whatever ELB it's attached too.