# How to create machine images that are identical between staging and production, but need different files (SSL certificates)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I'm using [Packer](https://packer.io/), and I'm new to creating machine images. Although I've created and deployed Docker containers before.

One concept I'd like to apply to the machine image building that I've found useful with Docker images is using the same exact image for staging testing that gets deployed to production. The different environments behave differently due to different environment variable values being passed in on startup, which in the case of Docker containers is often handled by a startup script ("entrypoint" in Docker terminology).

This has worked fine for me, but now I need to handle SSL certificates (actual files) being different between staging and production. In the case of Docker containers, you could just mount different volumes to the container. But I can't do that with machine images.

So how do people handle this scenario with machine images? Should I store these important files encrypted externally, and `curl` them in a startup script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using a configuration management tool such as [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) or [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com) to do any environment/host specific configuration you need once Packer has deployed the bulk of the VM.

Alternatively you could do as you mentioned and simply have a startup script curl the appropriate SSL certs (or any other environment specific files/config) that are needed from some location. Considering you've tagged your question with [amazon-web-services](/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) you could use separate, private S3 buckets for testing or production and only allow certain instances access to the relevant buckets via IAM roles, protecting that data from being viewed by others or the wrong environment but also reducing the need to encrypt the data and then manage keys as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm actually coming from a DigitalOcean setup where I have complete Ansible playbooks that provision everything, which I've been using with Packer (it supports Ansible) to create the machine images. The reason I want to pre-bake as much as possible is because there is a lot of non-deterministic behavior if I run the playbooks at different times (sources go down, etc.) which I want to avoid by baking machine images. Also, I've been moving towards Google Compute/Container Engine and using Terraform to deploy, which is biased towards this "immutable" infrastructure style.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch EC2 instances using your AMI, you can specify tags. Inside instances you can use [AWS CLI to read these tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-tags.html), so you can craft a script to run when the system starts and load whatever external files as you want based on the tag values (as @ydaetskcoR suggested from a private S3 bucket).

This is also useful: [Find out the instance id from within an ec2 machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/find-out-the-instance-id-from-within-an-ec2-machine)