# Identifying the AWS instance that serves you

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-sdk

I'm using Elastic-Beanstalk to deploy my web server to multiple instances.
I configured an endpoint `/version` which I'd like the server to tell me which version it runs and hopefully from which instance I was handled (to validate that the LB works as expected for instance).

I would like something like this to work:

```
app.get('/version', function (req, res) {
  var instance = getInstanceInfo();
  res.end(instance + 'v0.0.2');
});
```

How would `getInstanceInfo()` look like?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out the instance id from within an ec2 machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/find-out-the-instance-id-from-within-an-ec2-machine)

Answer (score 0):

You could hit the EC2 metadata service directly at: http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

Or you could use the metadata service in the SDK: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/MetadataService.html