# how to get InstanceID via ec2 api?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instanceid

I need a function wich tells me the instanceID, I was searching [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html) for a function, but you always need the id... Yeah and this is the problem.

I'm not allowed to use the console, need to find it out via a script.

I saw the AWS.MetadataService [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/MetadataService.html#request-property), but I can't handle it. I just can see single pieces but I don't know how to match them right, to geht what I want. At the moment I have this

```
var meta  = new AWS.MetadataService();

meta.request("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/", function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

But ofc this dont works... What needs to be in the path parameter?

Comment: Is your script running on the instance for which you need the ID? If so, I think you're looking for `AWS.MetadataService`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out the instance id from within an ec2 machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/find-out-the-instance-id-from-within-an-ec2-machine)

Comment: yes I saw the AWS MetadataService but I have no clue how to use it, I'll edit my question to show you my struggles

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your script is running on the EC2 instance for which you want the ID, you can get the EC2 instance ID from the instance meta-data. This command will give you the EC2 instance ID (eg. i-12345678):

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

Full docs for the meta-data can be found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

**Update:**

For something in Node, try this:

```
var meta  = new AWS.MetadataService();

meta.request("/latest/meta-data/instance-id", function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Don't include the `http://` and host parts. Just the final path.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking from ec2 api you can use the `aws ec2 describe-XXX` command for example

```
[xxx@IP-xxxx ~]# aws ec2 describe-addresses
{
    "Addresses": [
        {
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "InstanceId": "i-YOUR INSTANCE ID",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-xxxx",
            "AssociationId": "eipassoc-xxxx",
            "NetworkInterfaceOwnerId": "xxxx",
            "PublicIp": "xxxx",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-xxxx",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "xxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

you can also use `aws ec2 describe-instances` its pretty complete and return all info about the instance include the `InstanceId`

Comment: already tried this but i get `{ [MissingParameter: The request must contain the parameter instance id]
  message: 'The request must contain the parameter instance id',` So as I said, the instanceId is always needed

Comment: If you run it from the instance, it works - I've used it many times and I put an example from a running instance