# How to get self Instance Id of the running EC2 instance using boto?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

Using python boto API (not Boto3), how to I fetch for the self-instance ID of the CPU running the script in the user-data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out the instance id from within an ec2 machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/find-out-the-instance-id-from-within-an-ec2-machine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [boto](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/) to retrieve the instance ID from the local metadata service, as follows:

```
import boto.utils
meta = boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()
id = meta['instance-id']
print('instance ID:', id)
```

Note that [boto3 does not include this capability](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/313). One option is to simply use the native urllib package to query directly from the metadata service, as follows:

```
# For python v2
import urllib2
id = urllib2.urlopen('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').read()
print('instance ID:', id)

# For python v3
import urllib.request
id = urllib.request.urlopen('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').read().decode()
print('instance ID:', id)
```

Alternatively, you could pip install and use [adamchainz/ec2-metadata](https://github.com/adamchainz/ec2-metadata), as follows:

```
from ec2_metadata import ec2_metadata
print('region:', ec2_metadata.region)
print('instance ID:', ec2_metadata.instance_id)
```