# How do I programmatically get the Digital Ocean ID of the current Droplet from within the Droplet?

Tags: digital-ocean, devops, provisioning, droplet

I am setting up monitoring and log aggregation on my AWS and Digital Ocean servers, and I want to be able to include a Droplet ID in the meta-data for my log messages from Digital Ocean.

On AWS there is a way to get the Instance ID from inside the instance: [How to get the instance id from within an ec2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/625644/5114)

I'm looking for something similar in Digital Ocean so I can have a unique ID in my logs to identify a droplet.

I'm not looking for something like the hostname, since hostname can be set to anything in /etc/hostname. I might have multiple web servers behind a load balancer, all answering to the same hostname. IP addresses can change, so I don't want that.

I want a unique ID to help me find my Droplet in the API or web console, and I want to be able to get it from a shell script running on the Droplet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `curl http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/id` within the droplet, that will get you the ID of the droplet.
If you want to use it in a shell script, you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
droplet_id=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/id)
echo "droplet id: $droplet_id"

# use $droplet_id in your script whenever you need to identify the droplet

...
```

Answer (score -1):

In new version of API2

`https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/11111111`

11111111 - droplet ID