# How to use powershell to get EC2 instance public IP and private IP address? And list the IPs for these instances

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2

If I know EC2 Instance ID and EC2 Instance Name,

How to use powershell script to get EC2 instance public IP and private IP address through this information? And list the IPs for these instances

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already done so.

How about downloading and install the AWs PowerShell tools and use their native cmdlets to extract this information.

> AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell
>
> The AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell lets developers and
>   administrators manage their AWS  services from the Windows PowerShell
>   scripting environment. Now you can manage your AWS  resources with the
>   same Windows PowerShell tools you use to manage your Windows
>   environment
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/powershell
>
> AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell Users Guide
>
> The AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell are a set of PowerShell cmdlets
>   that are built on top of the  functionality exposed by the AWS SDK for
>   .NET. The AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell enable you to script
>   operations on your AWS resources from the PowerShell command line.
>   Although the cmdlets are implemented using the service clients and
>   methods from the SDK, the cmdlets provide an idiomatic PowerShell
>   experience for specifying parameters and handling results. For
>   example, the cmdlets for the PowerShell Tools support PowerShell
>   pipelining—that is, you can pipeline PowerShell objects both into and
>   out of the cmdlets.
>
> The AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell are flexible in how they enable
>   you to handle credentials including support for the AWS Identity and
>   Access Management (IAM) infrastructure; you can use the tools with IAM
>   user credentials, temporary security tokens, and IAM roles. The AWS
>   Tools for Windows PowerShell support the same set of services and
>   regions as supported by the SDK.
>
> http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/powershell/latest/aws-pst-ug.pdf

(Get-EC2Instance -Filter $filter_reservation).Instances

```
InstanceId : i-5203422c
ImageId : ami-7527031c
State : Amazon.EC2.Model.InstanceState
PrivateDnsName : ip-10-251-50-12.ec2.internal
PublicDnsName : ec2-198-51-100-245.compute-1.amazonaws.com
StateTransitionReason :
KeyName : myPSKeyPair
AmiLaunchIndex : 0
ProductCodes : {}
InstanceType : t1.micro
LaunchTime : 12/11/2013 6:47:22 AM
Placement : Amazon.EC2.Model.Placement
KernelId :
RamdiskId :
Platform : Windows
Monitoring : Amazon.EC2.Model.Monitoring
SubnetId :
VpcId :
PrivateIpAddress : 10.251.50.12
PublicIpAddress : 198.51.100.245
StateReason :
Architecture : x86_64
RootDeviceType : ebs
RootDeviceName : /dev/sda1
BlockDeviceMappings : {/dev/sda1}
VirtualizationType : hvm
InstanceLifecycle :
SpotInstanceRequestId :
License :
ClientToken :
Tags : {}
SecurityGroups : {myPSSecurityGroup}
SourceDestCheck : False
Hypervisor : xen
NetworkInterfaces : {}
IamInstanceProfile :
EbsOptimized : False
```

See also:

> AWS EC2 Windows Instance – Get instance details
>   https://aaronsaikovski.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/aws-ec2-windows-instance-get-instance-details/
>
> How to get the instance id from within an ec2 instance? How can I find
>   out the instance id of an ec2 instance from within the ec2 instance?
>   [How to get the instance id from within an ec2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/how-to-get-the-instance-id-from-within-an-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 0):

To view an individual EC2 Instance's Private IP, run this, substituting your specific InstanceId and region:

```
(Get-Ec2Instance -InstanceId i-9999999999999999 -Region us-east-1).Instances.PrivateIpAddress
```

For the public (if it has one) use:

```
(Get-Ec2Instance -InstanceId i-9999999999999999 -Region us-east-1).Instances.PublicIpAddress
```

If the EC2 Instance has a Public IP and you want to know whether it is and Elastic IP (static) or assigned from AWS public IP pool, you can check the OwnerId of the NetworkInterface Association. For Elastic IP's, the OwnerId will be your account id; for Public IP's assigned from the AWS IP Pool, it will be something with "amazon", such as "amazon-ebs" or just "amazon":

```
$AccountId = Get-AWSAccount
$ec2 = (Get-Ec2Instance -InstanceId i-99999999999999999 -Region us-east-1).Instances
if ($ec2.PublicIpAddress) {
    if ($ec2.NetworkInterfaces.Association.IpOwnerId -like $AccountId) {
        Write-Output ("Elastic IP: {0}" -f $ec2.PublicIpAddress)
    }
    else {
        Write-Output ("AWS Public IP Pool {0}" -f $ec2.PublicIpAddress)
    }
}
```

Be aware that if your EC2 is using the AWS Public IP Pool that none will be assigned when the Instance is powered off. It is released when powered off and gets a new one when the Instance is powered back on. Refer to [Amazon EC2 Instance IP Addressing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html) for more details.