# AWS EC2, command line display instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Do you guys know if we can display the EC2 instance type using command line?

Currently, I only have access to the command line of an EC2 instance. Is there a command line that I can type to display the type of instance. eg, `p2.8xLarge` or `g.16x` etc.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Yes - you can use the `meta-data` endpoint to retrieve information about your EC2 instance type via the command line. This command will work if you are using IMDS v1:

```
> curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type
t1.micro
```

But note that [IMDS v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-instance-metadata-service.html) is now the default! Running the above command on an instance that only allows v2 will result in "401 - Unauthorized".

[See this page for more information about the available commands.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)

If interacting with IMDS v2, you would issue these commands instead:

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"`
curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type
```

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to <> port 80: Connection refused. Despite querying it form within the instance.

Answer (score 13):

To get the EC2 instance type, run one of these commands depending on your Linux distribution:

**Amazon Linux:**

```bash
ec2-metadata --instance-type
```

**Ubuntu:**

```bash
ec2metadata --instance-type
```

If neither ec2-metadata nor ec2metadata is available, fall back to this:

```bash
wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type
```

All commands will output just the instance type value, like `t2.micro`.

Comment: This works for IMDS v2. It should now be the accepted answer.

Comment: does not work for me, I get `Command 'ec2-metadata' not found`

Comment: For me the command was `ec2metadata`

Comment: I get a `ec2metadata: command not found` on a t3a.2xlarge instance, so I'm not sure this is a good answer :(

Comment: This worked for me: `ec2-metadata | grep "instance-type"`

Comment: Linked answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/how-to-get-an-aws-ec2-instance-id-from-within-that-ec2-instance

Answer (score 1):

Once you get access to ec2. Type:

```
ec2-metadata | grep "instance-type"
```