# Create a script to retrieve AWS instance metadata and store it in a file. is it possible to write in yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops

please tell me the step by step approach.

Comment: please tell me the step-by-step process how to approach.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `ec2-metadata > filename` -- see: [How to get the instance id from within an ec2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16527884/174777)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html

All you need is here. For simple, you can use this command to get AMI ID or Security Groups:

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id`
`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/security-groups`

If you want to put it in the file, just put the > at the end of command:

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/security-groups > test.txt`